# Prove that the union of these linear equations is the natural numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have this list of linear equations which I've arranged in this manner to show off certain patterns:

\begin{matrix}
         2n+0 & & & \\
&&&4n+3 \\
         8n+1 & & & \\
&&&16n+13 \\
        32n+5 & & & \\
&&&64n+53 \\
      128n+21 & & & \\
&&&256n+213 \\
      512n+85 & & & \\
&&&1024n+853 \\
    \vdots    & & & \vdots \\
2^{2k+1}n+\frac{4^k-1}{3} & & & 2^{2k+2}n+\frac{10 × 4^k-1}{3} \\
 \end{matrix}

with $n$ and $k$ $\in [0, \infty)$

- I need to prove that the union over all values these equations produce is the natural numbers. Thanks in advance for any help!

---

Side note: I'm actually just trying to find out as much as possible about these constants as they keep cropping up in the work i'm doing. 
Properties I know of:

- Twice a constant plus the following constant is one less than a power of two.
- $C_{i+2} = 4C_i+1$

If you know of anything that could be useful for me to look at I'd also be grateful for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Note that a number $x$ avoids the first three sets $$$$ if and only if $x=1$ mod $2$, $x=1$ mod $4$, and $x=5$ mod $8$. Can you generalize this to calculate $x$ mod $2^n$ for each $n$, if $x$ avoids *all* your sets? Do you see why no such $x$ exists? *SUBHINT: show that for any number $y$, there is some $n$ such that for all $m, k>n$, $y$ mod $2^m$ and $y$ mod $2^k$ are the same.*

(In case you're not familiar with mod, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic).)

Comment: I'm familiar with mod, but I'm terrible with algebra. I always work of intuitions about numbers rather than the algebra. I'm good at understanding things. Terrible at proving them.


It may take a little while to see why those numbers in particular are useful. Thanks for the tips though!

Comment: @BenCrossley-hobbyist It's less those specific numbers - although you will need to look at the pattern eventually, at least a little bit (re: my subhint) - and more the fact that each linear equation tells you one more fact about $x$: by the $n$th equation, you know (assuming $x$ has missed each linear set so far) what $x$ mod $2^k$ is for each $k<n$. So with each equation, you're grabbing "half" of the numbers that are left.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that $(mod 2^k)$ there is always 1 position unfilled, and that is filled in, in 2 iterations time.

I spotted the pattern before wanting to prove it. So, I can see 'that' it works. I just don't know how to turn my intuitions into algebra and thus a proof.

I think the hints are only going to lead me towards what I already know.